# "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory." but it's not a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

```
<div id="container" class="<%=GetCssClass%>">
```

This code was working previously and now returns the error in the title, which doesn't make sense since the only thing that property can return is "index" or "style1", i.e. there are no slashes, backslashes, tildes or periods.

How is it possible to get this error if there's nothing that can be interpreted as trying to access something in another directory (not even an href property)?

```
 public string GetCssClass
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["GetCssClass"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["GetCssClass"] = "index";
        }
        return (string) ViewState["GetCssClass"];
    }
    set { ViewState["GetCssClass"] = value; }
}
```

But we just found the problem. A user control used one too many "../" in its href and, I suspect, that the first place the program knows that there's a problem is when it hits its first encounter with a server-side property (the problem was earlier and I had deleted all the other more difficult properties and was left with this, obviously innocuous, GetCssClass property).

If someone can explain why this happens and why the error doesn't point to the actual problem (the user control, in this case), I'll award the answer to them.

Comment: I don't think the issue is here. It is more likely trying to access a resource outside of this app, e.g. `../../AnotherVirtualDirectory/Scripts/somescript.js`

Comment: You may want to post your web form's code, as well as the code for  `GetCssClass`.